# Spring Integration-SFTP: Copy from one remote directory to another remote directory

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am using spring integration to pull files from remote sftp server. One requirement is that after pulling file from remote server directory (into local), it is needed to archive a copy of the pulled file into a different directory on same sftp server.

I checked the different options [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/sftp/inbound/). There are file synchronization or file copy options to local. But didn't find an option for remote.

Should I try something else other than spring integration? I'm using spring integration because it is already part of app. This is a new requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that purpose you should consider to use `SftpOutboundGateway` with the `Command.MV`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway

> The `mv` command has no options.
>
> The `expression` attribute defines the "from" path and the `rename-expression` attribute defines the "to" path. By default, the `rename-expression` is `headers['file_renameTo']`. This expression must not evaluate to null, or an empty `String`. If necessary, any remote directories needed will be created. The payload of the result message is `Boolean.TRUE`. The original remote directory is provided in the `file_remoteDirectory` header, and the filename is provided in the `file_remoteFile` header. The new path is in the `file_renameTo` header.